# Recursive Function that adds two variables passed to it

Tags: c++, recursion, increment, decrement

```
int mult2_recurse(int a, int b) {
}
```

Hello, I'm trying to fill in this function, which is passed 2 variables - called with different variables a couple times. I have to add the two variables without using any of *, /, +, =, *=, /=, +=, -= operators. I can only use ++ and/or -- operators. Can someone help me? I've tried numerous ways and can't seem to wrap the logic around my head.

Comment: Show one of the ways you've tried so we have a frame of reference.

Comment: Why would anyone *not* want to use the addition operator?

Comment: @wallyk It's probably a course assignment.

Answer (score 5):

For unsigned solution is:

```
unsigned add2_recurse(unsigned a, unsigned b){
    return (0 == b) ? a : add2_recurse(++a, --b);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, very nice. Very, very nice.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this however it crashes after calling it twice with two different variables.

Comment: @Chris22 please use site like repl.it to show your code which crashed.

Comment: I gave the solution for `unsigned` case which you tried to use in signed case without changing.